# Formatting data labels in Excel charts using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to change the data labels for the picture below from decimals (0.8102), like that of the blue part, to percentage (81.02%), like the red part of the stacked chart.

I have tried recording a macro but it does not show any code for the formatting of data labels.

[image]

Comment: May you teach me how you can make it appear like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
```