# Excel VBA - a macro to 'Format Data Series - Gap Width' in a chart?

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have to change the design of about 100 charts in Excel 2011, and I'm trying to speed things up a little with macros.

The problem is that Excel doesn't want to simply record some actions into a macro, it seems they need to be manually written.

I've managed to make a macro for changing the formatting of Data Labels using tips from this thread:
[Formatting data labels in Excel charts using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232870/formatting-data-labels-in-excel-charts-using-vba)

But now I'd like to also edit Label Series- Gap Width percentage, through a macro. I don't know the exact VBA syntax for this action. Maybe someone here can help.

I've tried

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataSeries.GapWidth = "110%"
```

But it didn't work. Run-time error 438, Object doesn't support property or method.

Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Comment: Why `"110%"`??? Or is a Typo?? Can you share a screen shot of the chart??

Comment: It's not a typo, default value is 150%.

The value refers to the width (thickness) of the bar. If you want the spacing between bars to be thicker than the bars themselves, you set it to be over 100%. 

Image:
http://i.imgur.com/Y22eBjw.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 110
```

Comment: Next time you're stuck, turn on the macro recorder and do it manually. The code might be ugly, but it will give you a better insight into the syntax you need.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs to do this in ExcelScript:

`selectedSheet.getChart("foo").getSeries()[0].setGapWidth(110);`